# Porting GCC specific ASM code to MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly

Basing on that code I found on google (which is working fine on GCC compiler)

```
#define ASM __asm__ __volatile__
void MyFunc()
{
    ASM("enc_start:\n\t");
    printf("Hello, world!");
    ASM("enc_end:\n\t");
}
int main()
{
    unsigned int addr, len;
    ASM("movl   $enc_start, %0\n\t"
        "movl   $enc_end, %1\n\t"
        : "=r"(addr), "=r"(len));
    printf("Address of begin of function: %X", addr);
    printf("Len is of: %d bytes", len);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to convert it in visual studio, I tried but I failed. I don't even know if that's possible. Can you please convert it for me or at least giving me a similar way for get the same result ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `__asm__` is an extension from gcc. MSVC has similiar extensions but with different syntax, look it up in the documentation.

Comment: Note: GCC **is very different** from VS!

Comment: @Paranaix the entire `asm` snippet is what `gcc` calls `extended asm`, so this is basically a `C` program with `asm` code wrote specifically for `gcc`. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: @user2485710 Yes and you want what from me? Havent I exactly stated this?

Comment: @Paranaix just saying that it's not just the `__asm__` keyword ;)

Comment: @user2485710 Well ok, thats a point. But as Im not working with gcc and theres this explicit `#define` at the top I thought that this was a syntax introduced by the user. Do you know whether `asm` is case sensitive?

Comment: Yeah I know that __asm__ is an extension of GCC(and that in visual studio it is _asm or __asm, and __volatile__ is __volatile or just volatile), but I wanted to know if this code could somehow be converted.

Comment: Sure it can. Do we do it for you? Surely not.

Comment: .... Thanks a lot I guess, atleast can you tell me how those $variables can be used like that in visual studio?

Comment: @AlexanderKim nope, that is `extended asm` it's the name that `gcc` gives to this kind of syntax for `inline asm`, you can still write `inline asm` that is not _`extended asm`_ in gcc; it's a compile feature that gives you more flexibility while writing `asm` code; remember that `asm` doesn't have a well defined syntax across the platforms, so even with the same target the fact that each compiler has its own syntax is somehow implicit and you should expect that. Regarding how to do this the polite answer is to start learning MSVC `asm` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx

Comment: @Paranaix AFAIK yes, it's case sensitive, any keyword that I know of is case sensitive in gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's inline assembly doesn't support labels IIRC, and without them, the whole snippet is useless. What are you trying to accomplish in the first place?

You can capture the current value of EIP in VS's inline assembly **as the function is executing**, but not externally.

By the way, even in GCC, it won't capture the address and length of the entire function's body. It'll capture address and length of the function sans the prologue and the epilogue code. To get function's real range, generate the MAP file and parse it.

I vaguely recall Visual Studio has prologue/epilogue size as predefined macros. I might be mistaken on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a pointer to function to get the starting address of a function, but in the case of Visual Studio, in debug mode, it's a pointer to a branch instruction (part of a branch table) that branches to the function. This would require that you check to see if the pointer points to a branch instruction and if so, decode the branch instruction to determine the start of the actual function.